# Icons don`t look the same on all devices

Tags: android

In my app, the users can edit their name.

Here is an example for 1 user that changes his name so it will look like this:

[image]

**This is the data that will update the database every time the user will update its profile:**

```
name.getText().toString();
```

**And this is how I am getting this string from the database:**

```
 name.setText(documentSnapshot.get("name").toString());
```

So far so good, but I have noticed that that the funny caterpillar icon looks different on different phones.

Here is how it looks on 2 more phones:

**1)Wait hold on, why is it orange???**

[image]

**2)Well, not too bad it's green and looks the same:**

[image]

---

Why is this happening?

I was sure that when the user enters the icon as a text it will just translate to ASCII, was I wrong?

Comment: [shrimps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrimp) actually look whole different ...

Comment: See: https://emojipedia.org/bug/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each device implements it own set of emoji, that's completely normal. You can add your own emojis to your project if you want all look the same